# Change the second Transform Algorithm in enveloped method using Python signxml library

Tags: python, xml, digital-signature

I am working with a python program that needs to sign an XML file using signxml library with the algorithms specified below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfrWH.png)

So, I created mi signer with de following options:

```
signer = XMLSigner(c14n_algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315",
                   method=methods.enveloped
                   )
signer.namespaces = {None: namespaces.ds}
nodo_raiz_firmado = signer.sign( 
    data=nodo_DE,
    key=clave_privada,
    cert=clave_publica
)
```

and the signature obtained with this method is the next (look at the second transform algorithm):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi8MA.png)

My problem is: How do I tell signxml to use `Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"` for the second Transform algorithm instead the default one?

I review the signxml docs and don't found any reference to second transform algorithm.